# How can I use variables in blade file from _variables.scss?

Tags: laravel

In resources/sass/app.scss file of laravel 7 app I can reference variables defined in resources/sass/_variables.scss as :

```
@import 'variables';
...
.page_content_container {
    @if ($debug_mode) {
        border: 3px dotted yellow;
    }
...
```

But I failed to do the same in style block of blade file :

```
<style>
    @import 'variables';
    
    
    .input_group_label {
        @if ($debug_mode) {
            border: 2px dotted green ;
        }
        width: 25%;
    }
```

I got error :

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)
```

How can I do it ?

**modified  block # 2 :**

I modified in resources/views/livewire/auth/profile.blade.php :

```
<style>
    @import '/resources/sass/_variables.scss';
    
    
    .input_group_label {
    
        @if ($debug_mode)
            border: 2px dotted green ;
        @endif
        width: 25%;
    
    }

    .input_group_content {
        @if ($debug_mode)
            border: 2px dotted red;
        @endif
    }

</style>
```

but next I got error :

```
Undefined variable: debug_mode
```

debug_mode var is defined in resources/sass/_variables.scss :

```
...

$debug_mode: false;
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add @endif, use like this

```
.input_group_label {
        @if ($debug_mode) {
            border: 2px dotted green ;
        }
    @endif
        width: 25%;
    }
```